# Question(s) about custom attributes

Tags: product-attribute

I see where to add them, and I've created a new one called **mpn** (Manufacturer Part Number). **Type=Text**

How do I get that to appear by **default on every product** editing / entry page?

Also, I added it to one product by pressing **"Add Attribute"** on the **product page**. I then tried a **sample bulk upload** with one row of data and 2 column headers: **SKU and mpn**. It imported apparently without errors, BUT the new mpn data is not present in the product listing when I go back in to look at / edit the product.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have your new custom attribute appear in any product page on the admin panel, you have to assign it to a set or all sets in STORES -> Attributes -> attribute set

after that they will appear on the product lists and when you edit any product.

Comment: Thanks. Any reason why when I do a 2 column upload, the data I'm uploading won't "stick" in that attribute for that product?